# Ionic 3 Form validation [(ngModel)] and formControlName dont work together

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-forms

I want to validate email and phone number in ionic 3 but there something wrong. I can not use ngModel with form validation.

this is an error:

> ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.

this is my html form

```
<form  (ngSubmit)="done()" #registerForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="registerForm">
 <ion-col style="padding: 0px;" >
     <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="number" formControlName="mobileNumber"  placeholder="971000000000" name="Mobile" [(ngModel)]="register.Mobile" [brmasker]="{mask:'971000000000', len:12}" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <p *ngIf="mobileNumber.errors.pattern" class="danger" padding>Phone number is not valid.</p>

</ion-col>

<ion-col style="padding: 0px;">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="email"  placeholder="{{lang.Labels.Email}}" name="email" [(ngModel)]="register.email" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <p *ngIf="email.errors.pattern" class="danger" padding>Email is not valid.</p>
</ion-col>

  <div class="row row-no-padding div_right">
    <div class="col text-right">
      <button  ion-button class="submit-btn" full type="submit" [disabled]="!registerForm.form.valid">{{lang.Buttons.next}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this is .ts file

```
 import {NgForm, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators,FormBuilder } from 
 '@angular/forms'


  mobnumPattern = "^((\\+971-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$"; 
  emailPattern = "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$";
  registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder) {

 this.registerForm = new FormGroup({
  mobileNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(this.mobnumPattern)),
  email: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern))
 });

 }
```

Comment: Try with : name="mobileNumber"

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it s still same. Am i should delete ngModel ?

Comment: Try an check may be this will work

Comment: If you want to show data in HTML also while changing [toWayBinding] then use NgModel

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I check already it s not working. still same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Set `[ngModelOptions]` to `true` like:

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

Or define your `FormGroup` like:

```
const registerForm = new FormGroup({
    mobileNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(this.mobnumPattern)),
    email: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern))
   });
```

and in HTML remove `name` and `[(ngModel)]` property

Comment: Angular Version?

Comment: angular 4 , ionic 3.13 ,Cordova 7

Comment: plucker or stackBlitz would be better